# Datatables Child Row issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have searched extensively both on and off of this website for an answer and can't seem to find anything.

I'm currently using Datatables for a project and I am using the child row feature that DT offers. Currently the way I am implementing this system is using HTML for the base lines and then the child rows call on a script (I used [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgotLfz/5/) as my base) to show the data.

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item 1</th>
        <th>Item 2</th>
        <th>Item 3</th>
        <th>Item 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td>data 1a</td>
        <td>data 1b</td>
        <td>data 1c</td>
        <td>data 1d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td>data 2a</td>
        <td>data 2b</td>
        <td>data 2c</td>
        <td>data 2d</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
 var data = [
    { key1 :'value1', key2 :'value2', key3 :'value3'},
    { key1 :'value1', key2 :'value2'}
];
function format (index ) {
    var json_data =  data[parseInt(index)];
    var op = '';
    $.each(json_data, function(key, value){
        op +='<div>' + key + ': '+ value + '</div>';
    });
    return op;
}

  $(document).ready(function () {

      var table = $('#example').DataTable({});

      // Add event listener for opening and closing details
      $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = table.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              // This row is already open - close it
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format($('#example td.details-control').index($(this)))).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          }
      });
  });

@import url('//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
 td.details-control {
    background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('http://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

My issue is that unlike the JSFiddle above, my code lines are not pulling any data other than the first line.

I have quite a bit of data for this project so I'm hoping to avoid starting over.
I have tried the JS version of DT and have never been able to get it to work, so the HTML method is what I went with. [Here's](http://test.keystrokedesigns.com/test.html) the link to the test page. I should add that the icons for the child rows on the left aren't showing up at the moment, but that's a different issue that's unrelated. Thanks in advance. :)

Edited to add:
I've attached a picture for clarification. Every child row is only showing only the data for the first line of the child row code...so every child row is using the link for Avila (which is the first line in the script as they're in alpha order.) and I need them to be showing the ones that are relevant.  The only changes I made to the JSFiddle I used as the base was changing the ID of the table and the "key" to "delivery"

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsc3P.png)

Comment: Could you be more explicit as to what's not working as you'd like, in that test page you linked?

Comment: The link to your example/test page is dead, consider removing it as it's not useful anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a combination of pagination, and this line:

```
row.child(format($('#example td.details-control').index($(this)))).show();
```

On your default pagination settings of 10 per page, they are all "Avila University".

`$('#example td.details-control').index($(this))` is always a number from 0 to 9 (with 10 per page). No matter which page you're on. If you go to page 3, you want to return an index more like 25, instead of 5 (which is what's happening now). Only the 10 rows on the current page exist in the DOM at that time, which is what jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) is looking at.

On your test page, if you change the 10 per page to 100 per page, and click a "Baker University" row, you'll see it return the correct information.

Here's a probable fix:

```
row.child(
    format(
        table.row(this.closest('tr')).index()
    )
).show();
```

(I've formatted it like this because it gets impossible to read all on one line, mixing DataTables and jQuery)

Get used to putting in `console.log()` calls everywhere for debugging purposes. I figured this out mostly from adding `console.log(index);` as the first line of the `format` function.

Comment: Thank you! That combined with changing the data-page-length worked perfectly!